# Efficial parallel.foreach on 200 calculative tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm running 200 tasks of math with parallel.foreach.
What is the most time efficient way to do it?

```
List<Task<double>> actions = new List<Task<double>>(200)
{
  Task<Double>.Factory.StartNew(() =>Tree.calc0(features)),
  Task<Double>.Factory.StartNew(() =>Tree.calc1(features)),
..................
...................
}


 Parallel.ForEach(actions, (action) => { result += action.Result; });
```

I want it to run no more than 0.5 second. current performance-> 2.5 seconds
Thanks!

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what Tree.calc does.  I don't think the TPL is your bottleneck.

Comment: calc131(double[] distances) { return ((distances[578] > 88.5) ? -0.249837477179356 : ((distances[986] > 86.5) ?((distances[142] > 83.5) ? 0.500000014956178 : 0.500000098288705) : ((distances[186] > 89) ? -0.129859832817679 : ((distances[989] > 84.5) ? ((distances[551] > 52.5) ? ((distances[490] > 55.5) ? 0.500000000021264 : 0.500000011428302) : 0.500000108661043) : ((distances[599] > 86.5) ? ((distances[437] > 40.5) ? ((distances[620] > 67.5) ? ... an so on, this calculation length is 47k chars.

Comment: Your real question lies in what that code accomplishes, and if that is the best way to do it. Personally, I *highly* suggest not using that many ternary operators. How would you ever debug?

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what you actually want to accomplish? Eg `I want to execute 200 different calculations on the same data set and sum the results`. Better yet, specify the algorithm you are trying to implement, perhaps there are parallel implementations out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Factory.StartNew` is not only creating the task, but it is also running it.

You don't even need to create a task, just invoke `calc` inside the `ForEach` loop.

<s>You actually need to create the task without running it</s>

```
Task<double> x = new Task<double>(() => Tree.calc0(features));
```

And then start the action on the `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: I must have a task array  for the loop:
 ' Parallel.For(0, 200, i =>
            {
                result += actions[i].Result;' the method 'new task' you suggested works a lot more slower than the factory.startNew. Is there any other way?

Comment: That's definitelly *not* what he suggested. You don't need tasks and `.Result`, if you simply want to call `calc0(features)` in parallel